# How to I execute a function only if a condition of an object's relation is met in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is probably not very clear and probably best illustrated with an example... I have an account model which has many users (which belongs to account). I also have a a method in a mailer that I only want to run if the account that the user is related to has a `state` of `"active"`. Basically, the user should only be sent the email if there account is active. The method in the mailer file looks like this at the moment.

```
  def pending_mail(document, user)
    @user = user

    mail(to: user.email, subject: t('emails.pending.subject') ... do |format|
      format.text
      format.html
    end    
  end
```

Comment: `return unless @user.account.active?`?

Answer (score 1):

The mailers only job is to render and send emails - not to handle business logic. Its not the mailers job to decide who gets an email or not.

This should be handled in the controller. For example:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @account.update(account_attributes)
      Accounts::UsersNotificationJob.perform_later if @account.active?
      redirect_to @account
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end

module Accounts 
  class UsersNotificationJob
    def perform(account)
      account.users.each do |user|
        UserMailer.pending_mail(user).deliver
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is an extremely naive implementation of a mass mailout and not something you actually should be deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You should have access the owning account through user.account, depending on how your model is defined. In which case you can just use a simple if statement.

```
  if @user.account.state == "active"
    mail blabla do |format|
     .....
    end
  end
```